# My semantic-ui js doesn't work with rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, semantic-ui

I'm using semantic-ui-sass gem. My semantic-ui css work fine. I have a menu on top of my page that I want to activate when an item is clicked.

applcation.html.erb:

```
<div class="ui navbar inverted menu">
  <a href="#">
    <i class="smile teal icon"></i>
  </a>
  <div class="menu">
    <a class="teal item">Home</a>
    <a class="teal item">Profile</a>
    <a class="teal item">Log out</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

application.js:
//= require jquery

```
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require semantic-ui
//= require semantic-ui/modal
//= require semantic-ui/tab
//= require_tree .
```

application.css.scss:

```
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */

 @import "semantic-ui";
 @import "semantic-ui/collections/menu";
 @import "semantic-ui/modules/tab";
```

app/assets/javascripts/posts/show.js:

```
// activate the clicked navbar menu
$('.navbar a').on('click', function(){
  $('.menu a').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

My page works outside rails with plain html, js, and css so my js code is correct.
What is it that I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I had to include all javascript inside $(document).ready(function(){}). I thought rails will automatically run all js inside document ready.